# How do you merge back your reverted changes+more changes from a backup branch?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

### **How do I merge a parallel branch (that was originally created before a revert) back to the trunk including the changes originally reverted from the trunk?**

I tried to google "how to merge back your reverted changes in SVN" but I can't seem to find the right way to do this. 
So suppose this is how the svn log for the trunk looks

```
    ** TRUNK **
Revision | Description
  501        Other people changes
  500        Reverted Changes to 498
  499        Added some files
  498        Production Release
```

When trunk was at version 499, I created a branch in `svn/branches/backup` and then I reverted the trunk back to 498 (see revision 500). Here's how the branch `svn/branches/backup` looks in SVN:

```
    ** BRANCH **
Revision | Description
    3        More changes
    2        Adding more changes
    1        Branch Created from trunk revision 499
```

Since then I have made some changes to `svn/branches/backup` branch (see revision 2 and 3) and other people have made changes to the trunk (revision 501). How do I merge my branch back to the trunk including the changes I originally reverted from the trunk i.e. excluding revision 500? (I was thinking this should be a merge with `no-ancestry` flag but it doesn't seem to be working or maybe I am going about this wrong)

**Here's what I am trying**: I was thinking the first thing to do is to apply the trunk to my branch - to bring my branch in-line with trunk. When I try, SVN wants to delete the files that I added in 499 from my branch probably due to them being deleted in revision 500. That is the wrong thing to do in this case. Any ideas on how I accomplish this merge correctly?

Comment: What do you want to get in result?! Think about conflict - edited or deleted files at first!

Comment: @LazyBadger: I don't understand your question. I know that I want to ignore that one particular trunk revision (500) in my branch. Every change made to the trunk apart from that revision I would like to keep

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out a **HACKEY** way to do it:

1. Update the `mergeinfo` property on the branch's checkout directory to contain `/trunk/ProjectDir:500` signifying that this branch was already merged with the trunk revision 500.
2. Merge the trunk into the branch and SVN will skip revision 500 and merge all the other changes that were made since you created your branch.
3. Commit the changes and you will have a higher revision number on your branch than the trunk.

Any subsequent merges of trunk to this branch and vice-versa will work as expected.

Comment: Alarm! Monkey with grenade! You **must** "merge range of revisions"  (keyword for G) (excluding r 500) in *normal* world

Comment: I don't agree with @LazyBadger. Although, I do see the point where this could be dangerous. In a typical case where you need to skip over a revision because of a revert, this approach makes sense to me. I've used this approach now in a few places and as long as you know what you are doing this solution has worked great for me!